# Achieve code reusability in inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I heard that code reusability we can achieve through inheritance, example: from a super class A, we can inherit the methods other than private methods to class B if it is extended and assume that both the classes are in same package. If this is the way to achieve code reusability in inheritance, then the same we can also get by creating an object of that class A right? I mean by creating an object we can access the public methods other than private methods right? why we need inheritance here? What is the code re usability in inheritance?

Comment: And what if you want to add a method to class A? Or change what one specific method does (while keeping the others)?

Comment: Also in what way are the explanations in the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) unclear?

Comment: The code re-usability is better achieved by use of interface and  composition.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever told you that gave you "bad" advice.

The **primary** goal of inheritance is **not** for re-use of code.

Classes are designed to build a **model** (aka abstraction) of reality; more specifically: a **helpful** model. And one core part of that: you don't write down `class A extends B` because it is *convenient* to do so, or because it helps you saving some coding efforts.

You do it, because in your problem domain, it simply makes sense that any A **is-A** B. That is the core of inheritance: two objects showing the *same* behavior.

And: to the contrary, the more relevant and accepted paradigm goes in the exact opposite direction: [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (favor composition over inheritance).

Please don't get me wrong: *code duplication* is one of the **worst** things you can do as programmer. So avoiding code duplication is one of the **core virtues** of good programming. But: inheritance creates coupling between classes; and it is not a good idea to prevent code duplication by giving up on isolation of classes. As inheritance can prevent you from re-using a class in another context.

Meaning: sometimes inheritance works nicely to prevent code duplication; but you have to be careful about it.

Comment: I have a example to suppoert this answer : I am working with cameras at work. We have devices that connect to different models, so we have an abstract "camera class" and every model inherits from this class to support specific functionality of that camera. It's a real world example and not difficult to understand.

Comment: Do not agree with "code duplication is one of the worst things you can do as a programmer". It is not that simple.. but I'm sure you know this too. ["Cloning considered harmful" considered harmful: patterns of cloning in software](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1466716)

Comment: The OP asks in the context of "using inheritance to achieve code reuse". Pretty narrow in my eyes. Beyond that: the problem with code duplication is maintenance, and the increased probability for introducing bugs. As soon as you start having almost identical clones... That is when the bugs come in. And too many people simply don't care about that. What I mean: in the real world the problems are created by people who just go forward and do copy/paste. So I prefer erroring on the side of "don't do it"...